# How can I destroy trees when placing a building in an RTS?

Tags: unity, c#, terrain, collider, tree

I am developing RTS game. When I build buildings on the Terrain, any trees that were in that location end up intersecting with the building.

I want to remove all trees from the building's footprint when placing.

Can I use the building's OnTriggerStay to detect tree colliders with a particular tag and destroy the trees? Or is there a better way to clear out these trees?

Comment: I don't think `OnTriggerStay` is the right tool for this job, since I wouldn't expect either your trees or the buildings to have Rigidbodies. At least one of the colliders needs a dynamic body to fire trigger messages. It sounds like you want something more like [`Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc.html) to get an array of all the trees overlapping your building's location.

Comment: I am in a poor level in the programming I can for now get trees in Terrain what about Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc It was something advanced

Comment: I don't understand your question. I recommend reaching out to a friend who has more practice with English to ask if they can help interpret or proofread for you, to he sure you're understood accurately.

Comment: Excuse me for a very me bad language to notice this after Edited question

Comment: I'll try Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
void Update()
{

    TerrainData terrain = Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData;
    ArrayList instances = new ArrayList();

    foreach (TreeInstance tree in terrain.treeInstances)
    {
        distanceG = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, tree.position);

        distance = Vector3.Distance(Vector3.Scale(tree.position, terrain.size) + Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (distance < closeRange)
        {
            // the tree is in range - destroy it
            print("1");
        }
        else
        {
            // tree is out of range - keep it
            instances.Add(tree);

        }
    }
    terrain.treeInstances = (TreeInstance[])instances.ToArray(typeof(TreeInstance));

}
```

Comment: You might want to mark this answer as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 0):

When you place the building you could search for any tree object in a certain radius around it and if it's less than a certain distance delete them. That way you wouldn't need collision.

You would need a reference to the trees in the scene to access their position information.

Comment: That looks to be what NADER LABBAD is already doing in the answer from a year ago, no?

Comment: My bad, didn't even notice the date. I'm still getting used to this sites UI

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your buildings have a rectangular base, you can use [`Physics.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) / [`Physics2D.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html) to get all the colliders which overlap the area where you want to put down the building and decide what to do with them depending on object type.